# Associating a pair of Strings in Java 7 and looping over them

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Given the following code:-

```
//setup code and import statements, including: 

private static String baseURL = Environment.getTestWebsiteURL();

public static String articleOneName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleOneName();
public static String articleTwoName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleTwoName();
public static String articleThreeName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleThreeName();

public static String articleOnePath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleOnePath();
public static String articleTwoPath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleTwoPath();
public static String articleThreePath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleThreePath();

public static String[] articlesPathArray = {articleOnePath, articleTwoPath, articleThreePath}


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
    driver = Driver.getURL();

    for (String s : articlesArray) {
        if (s == null) {
        //tell me which articles could not be found
            System.out.println("Could not find an article for: " + s + " , perhaps it wasn't created in the prior test");
        } else {
       //assuming array holds some path values, append to the baseURL
            driver.get(baseURL + s);

        }

}

@Test...

//run some test assertions against the baseURL + path website page that is returned
```

I need the code to loop through wherever the path variable holds a value and run tests.  The current solution is not helpful wherever the prior ArticleCreationTest fails to generate the article, because the variable simply contains null. So the text is: "Could not find an article for: null, perhaps it wasn't created in the prior test".

What I really need is to associate the articleName with the articlePath so the message is something like: "Could not find ArticleOne: perhaps is wasn't created", and then run the tests against all that were created.  Perhaps some kind of hashmap or 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code given,

```
public static String articleOneName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleOneName();
public static String articleTwoName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleTwoName();
public static String articleThreeName = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleThreeName();

public static String articleOnePath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleOnePath();
public static String articleTwoPath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleTwoPath();
public static String articleThreePath = ArticleCreationTest.getArticleThreePath();

public static String[] articlesPathArray = {articleOnePath, articleTwoPath, articleThreePath}
```

**It seems like, it is a list of articleNames and articlePaths**

```
List<String> acticleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> acticlePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The List will contain the Strings to be checked, which can be used for the tests.

> I need the code to loop through wherever the path variable holds a
>   value and run tests

You can check this condition by checking if `(s != null)`, currently you are checking for 
  `if (s == null)`

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, I am a beginner, so....to get the various names and paths into the List (from the other classes), I would need to something like the following??                                                             public static String populateArticleData(){
    List<String> articleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    articleNames.add(articleOneName);
    articleNames.add(articleTwoPath)//etc........
    List<String> articlePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    articlePaths.add(articlePathOne);//etc....
    }

Comment: Yes... You will have to populate the data.